# Hive error after alter table partition set location

Tags: hadoop, hive, alter-table

I have a table `TEST` with one partition `Profession`.
After the execution of

```
Alter Table TEST PARTITION(Profession='50') set location 'hdfs:/apps/hive/warehouse1/TEST/Profession=50';
```

Command was executed without errors;

Next query failed with exception:

```
cannot find dir = hdfs:/xxxxxxxx/apps/hive/wharehouse/TEST/Profession=50
```

this was the directory where the partition was originally set.

Ever executing a Alter Table to move the location back to the original does not fix the information.

My goal is to move old partitions over time from a SSD hdfs volume to a HDD hdfs volume.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: could you please send your table creation script, is test table an external table ?

Comment: is not an external table, here the script:  create table TEST (Id int, name string, address string, city string, zip string ) partitioned by (Profession string) stored as orc;

Comment: @franklinsijo without errors so no Error. The error is on the next query.

Comment: Sorry my bad.. read it wrong!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do **msck repair table Test**

Comment: I will, but more interested to know what can possibly generate the error, I try with other partitions and I get the same error.